# Can I ensure that a public key derived from a private key is unique?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-generation, asymmetric

In asymmetric cryptography, is it possible to ensure that public key derived from a given private key is unique, no matter the algorithm?

Comment: Your question may need some expanding so we can address it a little better. It sounds like this post on crypto may be in the right direction: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-many-rsa-keys-before-a-collision

Comment: @Lester - I've always wanted to attach [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk) somewhere, and I thought your question finally warrants it. As you'll soon learn, having a private key unique or not doesn't really matter, and I'm not entirely sure why would you want to assure that? Your question is mathematically/logically similar to asking _'if I choose a random time of the day to a millisecond precise, will it be unique to any other random selections of mine in the days of the coming year?'_. As you can see, you can't really assure that, nor should you depend on it.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot speculate on unknown algorithms.

With [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29), you can make *several* public keys which are all functionally equivalent, in that they all correspond to the same private keys. Namely, if the public modulus *n* is the product of *p* and *q*, and the public exponent is *e*, then *e'=e+k*lcm(p-1,q-1)* will be another valid public exponent for the same modulus, and corresponding to the same private key, for any integer *k* ("lcm" is the [Least Common Multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)). This allows you to compute an infinity of distinct public keys for one private key. (But it is not recommended *at all* to make more than one of these public keys public: combining two such keys reveals the private key quite easily.)

If you want unicity of public key, for some notion of unicity, then you have to arrange that yourself.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Do you know other algorithms that make my answer "true"?

Comment: With DSA and ECDSA, there is only one public key which matches a given private key -- provided that the key pair was correctly generated (it depends on whether the person who generates the key pair is a potential attacker or not). There can still be some possible variations in _encoding_.